# Ayuda con sentencia If durante ingreso de datos en MySQL en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7

requiero ayuda con la siguiente sentencia

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tarjetas (id, monto, codigo, serial, usuario, id_pedido)
      VALUES(null, '$monto', ' $codigo', '$serial', '$user', '$id_pedido')"; 

  $resultado_ingreso = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or $error= (mysqli_error($db));


}

if (!$resultado_ingreso){
$_SESSION['msn_pedidos_entrega']  = "Algo ha Ocurrido<br>" . $error;
} else {
```

La sentencia tal cual como esta obtiene los datos a insertar en la tabla **tarjetas** de un **foreach**, en una sola ejecución se pueden agregar por ejemplo 10 nuevas filas a mi base de datos, pero si 1 de esas 10 filas no es admitido por mi base datos por configuración previa de las llaves UNIQUE se puede producir un error con esa sola fila pero no con las 9 filas restantes y me gustaría que la sentencia fuera que así se agreguen 9 de los 10 datos como se genero 1 error entonces quede en el mensaje de que algo ha ocurrido y no continúe ejecutando el script ya que luego del else vienen una serie de UPDATE y envíos de correos al usuario notificando de la asignación.

**Aca mi Function Completa**

```
function entregar_pedido(){
  global $db;

  $id_pedido = ($_GET['id']);
  $user = ($_GET['user']);


  $lote = $_REQUEST['lote'];
  $lote_pedido = str_replace("  ", " ", $lote);
  $datos = $lote_pedido;
// divides por espacios y cada 6 elementos, los elementos de cada fila
$temp = array_chunk(explode(' ', $datos), 6);
$ar = array();



foreach($temp as $key => $v) {
  // optienes el 1º elemento monto
  $ar[$key]['monto'] = array_shift($v);
  // optienes el ultimo elemento, serial
  $ar[$key]['serial'] = array_pop($v);
  // lo que queda es el codigo, lo unes con espacios
  $ar[$key]['codigo'] = implode(' ', $v);

  $monto =   $ar[$key]['monto'];
  $codigo =  $ar[$key]['codigo'];
  $serial =  $ar[$key]['serial'];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO tarjetas (id, monto, codigo, serial, usuario, id_pedido)
      VALUES(null, '$monto', ' $codigo', '$serial', '$user', '$id_pedido')"; 

  $resultado_ingreso = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or $error= (mysqli_error($db));


}

if (!$resultado_ingreso){
$_SESSION['msn_pedidos_entrega']  = "Algo ha Ocurrido<br>" . $error;
} else {

$status = 'ENTREGADO';
$admin = $_SESSION['user']['username'];
$concepto = "ASIGNACION DE TARJETAS";

$sqlUPDATE = "UPDATE pedidos SET
status_pedido = '$status'
WHERE id = '$id_pedido'";

if (mysqli_query($db, $sqlUPDATE)) {
$_SESSION['msn_pedidos_entrega']  = "Se ha Actualizado el STATUS del pedido..!!<br>";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($db);
//mysqli_close($db);
}


$query = "INSERT INTO bitacora (
id,
id_pedido,
status,
admin,
concepto) 
VALUES(null, '$id_pedido', '$status', '$admin', '$concepto')";
  //mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $resultado_ingreso = mysqli_query($db, $query) or mysqli_error($db);


if (count($ar)<2){
$t= "Tarjeta";
} else {
$t= "Tarjetas";
}
$_SESSION['msn_pedidos_entrega']  .= "Se ha entregado el Pedido con Exito.<br>";
$_SESSION['msn_pedidos_entrega']  .= "En esta Transaccion fueron asignadas " .count($ar)." ".$t." <br>";

$sql1="SELECT sum(monto) AS 'total'
  FROM tarjetas
  WHERE usuario = '$user' AND id_pedido = '$id_pedido'";
  $result1 = mysqli_query($db, $sql1);

  while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) 
{
  if ($row1['total']<1){
    echo "No se Ha encontrado Tarjetas Asignadas a este Usuario";
      } else {
        $_SESSION['msn_pedidos_entrega']  .= "Total de BsS Entregado ".$row1['total']." BsS<br>";
}
}

$sql2 = "SELECT tarjetas.*, users.nombre, users.email, users.username FROM tarjetas INNER JOIN users  ON tarjetas.usuario=users.idusuario WHERE usuario = '$user' AND id_pedido = '$id_pedido' ";
$result2 = mysqli_query($db, $sql2);
//if (mysqli_query($db, $query)){
$row2count =  mysqli_num_rows($result2);
//$row2 =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);

  $tarjetas = '<table class="table table-bordered table-hover ">';
  $tarjetas .= '<thead><tr>';
  $tarjetas .= '<th height="17" width ="20%" align="center">';
  $tarjetas .= 'MONTO';
  $tarjetas .= '</th>';
  $tarjetas .= '<th height="17" width ="20%" align="center">';
  $tarjetas .= 'CODIGO';
  $tarjetas .= '</th>';
  $tarjetas .= '<th height="17" width ="20%" align="center">';
  $tarjetas .= 'SERIAL';
  $tarjetas .= '</th>';
  $tarjetas .= '</tr></thead>';

while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
  $monto = $row2['monto'];
  $codigo = $row2['codigo'];
  $serial = $row2['serial'];
  $email_usuario = $row2['email'];
  $nombre_usuario = $row2['nombre'];

  $tarjetas .= '<tr>';

  $tarjetas .= '<td align="center">';
  $tarjetas .= $monto;
  $tarjetas .= '</td>';
  $tarjetas .= '<td align="center">';
  $tarjetas .= $codigo;
  $tarjetas .= '</td>';
  $tarjetas .= '<td align="center">';
  $tarjetas .= $serial;
  $tarjetas .= '</td>';
  $tarjetas .= '</tr>';
}
  $tarjetas .=  '</table>';

  $tarjetas_asignadas = $tarjetas;


$_SESSION['msn_pedidos_entrega']  .= "En total se le han asignado ".$row2count." tarjetas al usuario " .$user."<br>";

$email = $email_usuario;
$nombre = $nombre_usuario;
$asunto = "ASUNTO";
$cuerpo = "CUERPO DEL MENSAJE";

enviarEmail($email, $nombre, $asunto, $cuerpo);

$_SESSION['msn_pedidos_entrega']  .= '<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Se ha enviado un correo electronico notificando sobre esta asignacion de pedido..!!<br>';

}
}
```

Comment: Necesitas un `try` y un `catch`

Comment: Podrías utilizar [$mysqli->affected_rows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.affected-rows.html)

Comment: Hola @alanfcm gracias por tu rapidez en responder, crees que me puedas orientar en como debo implementar `try` y `catch` en mi codigo, he modificado y colocado el codigo completo de mi function..!

Comment: de hecho el error esta en la linea `$resultado_ingreso = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or $error= (mysqli_error($db));` son dos lineas distinas!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `try` y `catch` para continuar la ejecucion del bucle asi:

```
foreach($temp as $key => $v) {
  // optienes el 1º elemento monto
  $ar[$key]['monto'] = array_shift($v);
  // optienes el ultimo elemento, serial
  $ar[$key]['serial'] = array_pop($v);
  // lo que queda es el codigo, lo unes con espacios
  $ar[$key]['codigo'] = implode(' ', $v);

  $monto =   $ar[$key]['monto'];
  $codigo =  $ar[$key]['codigo'];
  $serial =  $ar[$key]['serial'];
  try {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO tarjetas (id, monto, codigo, serial, usuario, id_pedido)
          VALUES(null, '$monto', ' $codigo', '$serial', '$user', '$id_pedido')"; 

      $resultado_ingreso = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or $error= (mysqli_error($db));
  } catch (Exception $e) {
      // Aqui puedes desplegar el error si quieres
      continue;
  }

}
```

Comment: Así como gentilmente me sugieres el bucle se detiene si encuentra algun error haciendo el INSERT y no ejecuta el resto del codigo..??

Comment: Una pregunta desde el desconocimiento: ¿Es necesario ese `continue`?

Comment: @JoseMHerreraV el bucle no se detiene, para eso es el catch, para que no se detenga si encuentra error.

Comment: @JDev no estoy seguro si necesitas `continue` o no, seria de probar.

Comment: He implementado la sugerencia usando el `continue;` y funciona de manera correcta